# Video Thumbnail Question

Tags: extensions, custom-options, products-management

I was wondering if there was a way to add a video thumbnail on a product landing page. I know that there are extensions out there that allows me to put a video in the product detail page, but I want a video to automatically play when I hover over a product image. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Henry**, go to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706799/start-youtube-video-on-hover-mouseover). I think it will be resolved your problem.

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gpJN4/3/